# How can i wrap a function in c# same as using inline header function in C

Tags: c#

I am writing some class in c# that have a function

```
Print(string s)
```

In the last version i found out that this function called from many threads and every time this function called it should be locked. In C language i can rename this function to

```
PrintA(string s)
```

and change the header file to something like

```
#define Print(a) {Lock(PrintA) //
                  { //
                      PrintA(a) //
                  } //
                 }
```

Is it possible to write something like this in C#?
I just want to change one place instead multiple place all over the code.

Comment: why not adding a lock in the implementation of print? it's one place to change and you will get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no macros in C#. To add synchronization to a method, you can use:

```
void Print(string s)
{
    lock (lockObject) { PrintA(s); }
}
```

You'll need to define a lock object, simply add a field to your class

```
private readonly object lockObject = new object();
```

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` is less recommended as it uses `this` as the lock object, which means users can interfere with locking logic and cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock whole one method, you can decorate it with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` attribute:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void Print(string s)
{
    ...
}
```

For more specific control you'd have to use `lock` on a code block.